# Need to move li content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, list

I have multiple lists nested inside a parent list; each child list resides in a li with a class, while the titles for each nested list reside in an adjacent li in the parent list. The markup is as follows:

```
<div>
  <ul class="parent-list">
    <li>Nested List Title 1</li>
    <li class="child-list">
      <ul class="bullets">
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Nested List Title 2</li>
    <li class="child-list">
      <ul class="bullets">
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Nested List Title 3</li>
    <li class="child-list">
      <ul class="bullets">
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I need to do is move the nested lists with the class "bullets" into the li elements adjacent to their respective parent li elements (e.g. the first "bullets" list needs to go into the first li with "Nested List Title 1", second "bullets" list goes to the second li with "Nested List Title 2", etc.).

After moving the ul content, I will destroy the li.child-list elements with .remove().

I've been toying around with .appendTo() and the .next/.prev functions, but things aren't rendering out right. Ideas?

Tried to take some insights from [jquery insert html into list before a child ul-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680452/jquery-insert-html-into-list-before-a-child-ul-tag) but haven't gotten very far.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. can you put the expected HTML in your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the li children of parent ul which does not have the `child-list` class and then append the next sibling li's ul to it like

```
$('.parent-list > li:not(.child-list)').append(function(){
    return $(this).next('.child-list').remove().find('ul')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Z6Ye/)